# Ria Services Composition one-to-one, how to?

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

I have some code using RIA service with compositon attribute. I can send data to client and it works fine, but I can't write my hierarchy. It tells me that I need to create an EntitySet in a Domain Service, but this isn't what I want.

> This EntitySet of Type 'Inner'
>   does not support the 'Edit' operation.

Similar code with a composition to an ObservableCollection works fine.

```
public class Top
{
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("MyAssociation", "InnerId", Inner.THIS_ID)]
    public Inner Podmiot { get; set; }
    public Guid InnerId { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    public const String THIS_ID = "Id";

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

}
```

My DomainSerivce just has methods to Query, Insert and Update Top class.

Such code in Top would work, but I need a one-to-one composition, not a one-to-many

```
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("MyAssociation", THIS_ID, Inner.ForeignKeyOfTop)]
    public ObservableCollection<Inner> MyCompositeCollection { get; set; }

public class Inner
{
    public const String ForeignKeyOfTop= "TopId";

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid TopId{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the relevant DomainService code as well as the relevant code of the `Inner` entity?

Comment: ok, I have added some more code. I have tried changing the association, but with no luck so far.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Here is link that explains your scenaior a bit. I hope that helps: http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/Meet-the-EntityRef-and-the-AssociationAttribute.aspx